# What is the different between raising an event from Protected Virtual Void method or directly?

Tags: c#, events

I saw some tutorials and I couldn't understand why would they suggest to raise an event from Virtual Protected method, instead of directly, what is the difference?

```
public delegate void SomethingEventHandler(string s);
public event SomethingEventHandler Something;

public void Main() {

  // Raising an event
  OnSomething(); // Via method
  Something("something"); // Directly
}

protected virtual void OnSomething() 
{
  Something("something");
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See "*Design Guidelines for Developing Class Libraries*", [Event Design](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms229011%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

> **Do use a protected virtual method to raise each event. This is applicable only to non-static events on unsealed classes, not to structures, sealed classes, or static events.**
>
> Complying with this guideline allows derived classes to handle a base class event by overriding the protected method. The name of the protected **virtual** (**Overridable** in Visual Basic) method should be the same as the event name prefixed with `On`. For example, the protected virtual method for an event named `"TimeChanged"` is named `"OnTimeChanged"`.
>
> ⚠ **Important**
>
> Derived classes that override the protected virtual method are not required to call the base class implementation. The base class must continue to work correctly even if its implementation is not called.

Answer (score 8):

I guess that is mainly because of a basic principe called 'Don't Repeat Yourself' (DRY).

For example: you have to raise the `NotifyPropertyChanged` event when a property's value has changed. You want to do that from 10 properties in your code. You  can repeat raising that event from ten methods, or call a method that does that for you. If you have to change something to the event raising, you only have to do that once.

Also, making it `protected virtual` gives you the opportunity to override that functionality in a derived class.

Also note that for thread-safety, your raising should look like this:

```
protected virtual void OnSomething() 
{
     EventHandler d = Something;

     if (d != null)
     {
         d("something");
     }    
}
```

Comment: You can simplify this to `Something?.Invoke("something");` (in C# 6)

Comment: That is true. While the above might be better for new programmers who don't understand all this C# 6 syntax.